# How do I find passenger lists for ships embarking from Mexican ports to California?

Tags: immigration, manifest, ship, locating-records

I have a record (found on Ancestry.com) of the steamer Curacao arriving in San Francisco, California on 1 July 1905. She was laden with gold and also my great grandmother and grand uncle. The US records show the ship as embarking on 17 June 1905,from "Guaymas and Wayports" in Mexico.My great grandmother was shown to have embarked from Mazatlan.
I would like to find Mexican records of the same voyage. Perhaps they would tell me where my great grandmother embarked (if different than Mazatlan) and where she was from. Perhaps even a passport record.
Does anyone know how, where, and who to contact? I assume in Mexico.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely outside my expertise, and my Spanish is very rusty, but I have a couple of suggestions.

1. Check archives in Mexico for outbound passenger lists.  The Family Search wiki article [Mexico Archives and Libraries](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Mexico_Archives_and_Libraries) has contact information and research guides. Their list of records that might be found in the National Archives include passenger lists.
2. You can apparently get different search results from Google by going to the website of Google in that country and starting from there.  Experiment by searching https://www.google.com.mx/ and see what happens.
3. The article [How to See Google Search Results for Other Locations](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-see-google-search-results-for-other-locations/) talks about tools to let you restrict search results to domains in specific countries.  This might help when searching for search results from Mexican archives.

The Family Search [research portal for Mexico](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Mexico) and Latin American research guides may have sample letters in Spanish you can use as a guide for writing archives.

Edited to add: search Google Books for titles similar to  -  [Emigration and Immigration: Reports of the Consular Officers of the United States](http://books.google.com/books?id=kn6UTFzwr2IC&dq=Mazatlan%20mexico%20emigration&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (the linked title is from 1887 which is a bit too early) for reports on the conditions in Mexico that might have prompted people to come and go. You won't find your g-grandrelatives by name, but it did come up when I searched for  Mazatlan, and might have information about other ports.  See if you can find a volume closer to when your relatives departed Mexico.  There might be similar reports published in Mexico, too.

Also of interest: the section [Personal Narratives & Correspondence](http://www.loc.gov/rr/genealogy/bib_guid/immigrant/personal.html) from the Library of Congress' Reading Room Guide *Immigrant Arrivals: A Guide To Published Sources* cites this work:

> Davis, Marilyn P. Mexican Voices. American Dreams: An Oral History of
>   Mexican Immigration to the United States. New York: H. Holt, 1990.
>   xiv, 446 p., index. Interviews with legal and illegal immigrants, and
>   with those who help them cross the border. LC call number: E184 .M5D28
>   1990 LC control number: 90031640

There's a link on that page for the Library of Congress Catalog record.  You may be able to find it in a library near you by searching [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/) (you can tell WorldCat where you are by entering a zip code).

Comment: Thank YOU Jan! This gives me three or four more things to try that I hadn't thought of on my own. You're great!

Comment: @PeggyDeras I've added new ideas to the bottom of my answers.  Happy hunting!